# How to invoke a div from another jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have a jsp with multiple divs and another jsp with links to these divs. I would like to invoke a specific div on the click of a link.

First JSP

```
<html>
    <li>
        <a href="legals.jsp" class="line-lrg">  What is 'porting'?</a>
    </li>
</html>
```

legals.jsp(Second jsp)

```
<div id="tab-01" class="ta-body" role="tabpanel" tabindex="0">
    <h4>What is 'porting'?</h4>
    <p>
    Porting is....
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Write some JavaScript? It's not clear what your issue is.

Comment: For invoking divs in the same page we can do it like <a href="#tab-01" class="line-lrg">  What is 'porting'?</a> ryt. Is there any solution apart from javascript or jquery?

Comment: What do you mean by "Invoke a div"? How are these tabs implemented? If it's actual tabs, e.g., divs hiding and showing, then you're *already* using JS.

Comment: There are multiple questions in on jsp(they are links), corresponding answers in second jsp. I want the answer to get displayed on the first jsp by  question link click from the first jsp.

Comment: That doesn't provide enough info to help. If you're using something that implements tabs, eg, things are hidden, then you'll need JS to unhide them.

Answer (score -1):

In the First JSP, change `href="legals.jsp"`attribute to this:
`href="legals.jsp#tab-01"`

Comment: does legal.jsp load in the browser when the link is clicked?